# Header on all pages, footer in first page only

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am Basically a Perl Developer, new to VBA,
How to insert a Header in all the pages of a word document along side Footer only in the first page,

I tried recording macro but it's not working

I tried to insert a header first with Different First page disabled and then inserted Footer with Different First page enabled

It works in Word, but as a VBA macro, i cant able to create it

```
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
Selection.TypeText Text:="ssss"
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.TypeText Text:="ssss"
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

i can create a macro to insert Header and footer in all pages or header and footer in first page only, the thing i am struggling is Header on all pages and footer only in 1st page, pls guide

Comment: I tried to insert a header first with Different First page disabled and then inserted Footer with Different First page enabled

Comment: OK that is better, now please explain what you mean by "i cant able to create it"

Comment: The recorded macro does not doing its purpose, i can create a macro to insert Header and footer in all pages or header and footer in first page only, the thing i am struggling is Header on all pages and footer only in 1st page, pls guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really very simple. In the Word UI you first add your header with Different First page disabled. Then you add ***both*** header and footer with Different First page enabled. Your code needs to do the same, but without all the screen activity.

```
Sub AddHeaderAndFooter()
  With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Main header"
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = "First page header"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = "First page footer"
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
  End With
End Sub
```