# How to insert Header from blocks saved in Quick Parts using macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I haven't understood how to use the object structure in the VBA. I barely get by picking up pieces from stack overflow to accomplish my task. Thanks a lot for everyone who contributes here.

I need to set the header in a document from Quick Parts. I found this
[Header on all pages, footer in first page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858905/header-on-all-pages-footer-in-first-page-only/62860671#62860671?newreg=f8808d35ec7240d69482e2160f6dadac) that works if the header and footer are text only.
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range = "Header_2"

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Main footer"
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = "First page header"
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text = "First page footer"
```

Is it possible to add to the text in quotes - sendkeys() to use the functionality of {f3} that populates the header from quick parts?

Answer (score 1):

From my [page on using vba to insert building blocks](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock):

You need to, somehow, identify the building block:

1. Template
2. Gallery
3. Category, and
4. Name

> Recording a macro will work, to a limited extent.  Recorded macros
> will not work on someone else's system even if they have the same
> building blocks or even if they are a different user on the same
> computer. Recorded macros will not work if the template contains more
> than one building block with the same name, even if they are different
> types. Note that the file that comes with Word "Built-In Building
> Blocks.dotx" has many building blocks with the same names. You can use
> the Building Blocks Organizer and sort by name to see if there are
> multiple building blocks with the same name and in the same template.
>
> Because of these limitations, often you will need to actually write a
> macro.
>
> However, you can try recording one. The key is to use the Building
> Blocks Organizer to insert the Building Block when recording the
> macro, rather than a shortcut or another gallery/menu.
> [image]
> Any macro, recorded or written, should be stored in the same template
> that holds the building block. That way, if the macro is available,
> the building block is available.

### Writing a Macro

> To do this, you need to know:
>
> The name of the building block. If you have a unique name for the
> building block (no other building block of the same name exists in any
> building block entry location) then use Graham Mayor's macro found on
> [one of his sample macro pages](http://www.gmayor.com/word_vba_examples_3.htm). A variation is shown below.
> The name (and location) of the template that holds the building block unless the macro is in the same template
> How to insert a macro. See [Installing Macros](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) and [Install/Employ VBA Procedures (Macros)](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html).
>
> ```
> Building Block Name = "MyBB" (example in this macro, change to fit)
> ```
>
> **Situation 1 and 1a have the Building Block and the macro in the same template.** This simplifies coding because a macro can always tell
> the name and location of the template that holds it. That information
> is required to use a macro to insert a building block.
>
> **Situation 1** - template holds both the building block and the macro
>
> Here is the macro to insert that uniquely-named building block at the insertion point in the document:

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'  Will not work if there are multiple building blocks with the same name in the template! See below.
'
  Const sBBName As String = "MyBB" 'use the name of your building block instead of "MyBB"
'
  On Error GoTo Oops
  Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' Thank you Timothy Rylatt
  Application.Templates(ThisDocument.fullname).BuildingBlockEntries(sBBName).Insert Where:=Selection.range, _
    RichText:=True ' Insert MyBB Building Block
  Exit Sub ' We're done here
Oops: ' Didn't work - building block not there!
  MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block " & sBBName & " cannot be found in " & _
  ThisDocument.Name & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
  On Error GoTo -1
End Sub
```

> This and the following macro are both contained in a demonstration
> template that can be downloaded from my downloads page.

### Situation 1a - template holding building blocks and macro in same template - multiple building blocks with the same name

> In this situation, the previous  macro would confuse Word and give
> unpredictable (to the user) results. In this case, the macro needs to
> know both the gallery and category of the building block. The
> following macro assumes that the building block is stored in the
> AutoText gallery and in the General category. You can find the name of
> the gallery and category using the Building Blocks Organizer. Category
> names are plain text. Galleries are referenced in vba as Building
> Block Types and use constants. You can find a list of the constants
> for the different galleries here.

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'
' Assumes that the Building Block is of the type AutoText (wdTypeAutoText) in Category "General"
' See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243303(v=office.12).aspx
'
' This is based in part upon contributions from Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman - any errors remain mine
' Written by Charles Kenyon April 2021
'
  Const sBBName As String = "MyBB" 'use the name of your building block instead of "MyBB"
  Const sTempName As String = ThisDocument.fullname ' puts name and full path of template in string
'
  Dim oBB As BuildingBlock
'
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' Thank you Timothy Rylatt
  Set oBB = Application.Templates(sTempName).BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeAutoText) _
     .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks(sBBName)
  If err.Number = 0 Then
    oBB.Insert Selection.range, True
  Else
    MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block '" & sBBName & "' cannot be found in " & _
       ThisDocument.Name & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
  End If
lbl_Exit:
  On Error GoTo -1
  Set oBB = Nothing
End Sub
```

> This and the preceding macro are both contained in a demonstration
> template that can be downloaded from [my downloads page](http://www.addbalance.com/word/download.htm#MacroToInsertBB).

### Situation 2 - template holding building block is in Word Startup Folder and named MyBBTemplate.dotx

> This template, for some reason, does not hold the macro, it is in a
> separate template. We know the name of the container template. The
> name of the template containing the macro does not matter for our
> purposes.

```
Sub InsertMyBB()
'  Will not work if the Startup Folder is the root directory of a drive, i.e. C:\
'  For use with building block stored in a template loaded in the Word Startup Folder that does NOT hold this macro
'  Will not work if there are multiple building blocks with the same name in the template!
'
  Const sBBName As String = "MyBB" 'use the name of your building block instead of "MyBB"
  Const sTempName As String = "MyBBTemplate.dotx" 'use the name of your template instead of "MyBBTemplate.dotx"
  On Error GoTo NoStartupPath
  Const sStartupFolder As String = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdStartupPath)
'
  On Error GoTo Oops ' error handler
  Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' Thank you Timothy Rylatt
  Application.Templates(sStartupPath & "\" & sTemplateName).BuildingBlockEntries(sBBName) _
     .Insert Where:=Selection.range, RichText:=True ' Insert MyBB Building Block
  Exit Sub ' We're done here
NoStartupPath:
  On Error GoTo -1
  MsgBox Prompt:="No Startup Folder Set in Options"
  Exit Sub
Oops: ' Didn't work - building block not there!
  MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block " & sBBName & " cannot be found in " & _
  sTemplateName & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
  On Error GoTo -1
End Sub
```

### Situation 3 - Insert a building block with a unique name at a bookmark, regardless of location

> This macro does NOT care where the building block is stored but its
> name must be unique to have predictable results.

```
Sub InsertMyBuildingBlock_Bookmark()
' Charles Kenyon 09 April 2021
' based on Graham Mayor's macro at
' http://www.gmayor.com/word_vba_examples_3.htm
' In addition to checking the active template, add-in templates and the normal template,
' this macro looks in the building blocks.dotx template.
' Building Block name must be unique!
'
  Const BookMarkNAME As String = "delete" ' use the name of the building block - make variable if multiple bookmarks
'
  Dim oTemplate As Template
  Dim oAddin As AddIn
  Dim bFound As Boolean
  Dim oRng As range
  Dim i As Long
  'Define the required building block entry
  Const strBuildingBlockName As String = "Building Block Name"
  ' Set the range
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookMarkNAME).range
  'Set the found flag default to False
  bFound = False
  'Ignore the attached template for now if the
  'document is based on the normal template
   Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks ' Thank you Timothy Rylatt
   If ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate <> NormalTemplate Then
    Set oTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
    'Check each building block entry in the attached template
    For i = 1 To oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Count
     'Look for the building block name
       'and if found, insert it.
      If oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(i).Name = strBuildingBlockName Then
        oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(strBuildingBlockName).Insert _
          Where:=oRng
        'Set the found flag to true
        bFound = True
        'Clean up and stop looking
        GoTo lbl_Exit
      End If
      Next i
  End If
  'The entry has not been found
  If bFound = False Then
    For Each oAddin In AddIns
      'Check currently loaded add-ins
      If oAddin.Installed = False Then Exit For
        Set oTemplate = Templates(oAddin.Path & _
          Application.PathSeparator & oAddin.Name)
        'Check each building block entry in the each add in
        For i = 1 To oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Count
          If oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(i).Name = strBuildingBlockName Then
            'Look for the building block name
              'and if found, insert it.
            oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(strBuildingBlockName).Insert _
               Where:=oRng
            'Set the found flag to true
            bFound = True
            'Clean up and stop looking
            GoTo lbl_Exit
          End If
        Next i
    Next oAddin
  End If
  'The entry has not been found. Check the normal template
  If bFound = False Then
    For i = 1 To NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Count
      If NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(i).Name = strBuildingBlockName Then
        NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(strBuildingBlockName).Insert _
          Where:=oRng
        'set the found flag to true
        bFound = True
      End If
    Next i
  End If
  'If the entry has still not been found
  'finally check the Building Blocks.dotx template
  If bFound = False Then
    Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
    For Each oTemplate In Templates
      If oTemplate.Name = "Building Blocks.dotx" Then Exit For
    Next oTemplate
    For i = 1 To Templates(oTemplate.fullname).BuildingBlockEntries.Count
      If Templates(oTemplate.fullname).BuildingBlockEntries(i).Name = strBuildingBlockName Then
        Templates(oTemplate.fullname).BuildingBlockEntries(strBuildingBlockName).Insert _
          Where:=oRng
        'set the found flag to true
        bFound = True
       'Clean up and stop looking
        GoTo lbl_Exit
      End If
    Next i
  End If
  'All sources have been checked and the entry is still not found
  If bFound = False Then
    'so tell the user.
  MsgBox "Entry not found", _
    vbInformation, _
    "Building Block " _
    & Chr(145) & strBuildingBlockName & Chr(146)
  End If
lbl_Exit:
  set oTemplate = Nothing
  set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

> For more thoughts/ideas on inserting a building block at a bookmark,
> see this thread: [Updating bookmark with multiple building blocks](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?68715-Updating-bookmark-with-multiple-buildings-blocks-based-on-checkbox-status&p=409048#post409048) based
> on checkbox

Comment: Thanks! The insertion part works great... How can I set the selection to be header or footer on page 1 or 2?

Comment: @Dhuryodhan, see my edited answer for how to set a range to a header or footer.

Comment: Note John's response. I've updated my web page to show insertion at a range. I may update the answer at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a range variable, set it to the particular header or footer you want, then replace Selection.Range with that variable. To set a range variable:

```
Dim myRange as Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
```

The macro recorder tells me:

```
Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\jkorc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm"). _
        BuildingBlockEntries("I have a macro").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
        RichText:=True
```

Replace *Selection.Range* with **myRange**.

If the QuickPart is AutoText in the template attached to the document, you can use:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("I have a macro").Insert myRange
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how to set the range variable.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that.